# Homestead status 403 forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I am seeing 403 forbidden when trying to visit the url after setting up a homestead VM. I think my paths must be wrong but I cant figure out where..

I am on a Mac.

I have a file on my local machine which contains a Laravel project

```
/Users/<my-name>/Sites/laravel_projects/public/my-app
```

My homestead.yaml looks like

```
folders:
    - map: /Users/<my-name>/Sites/laravel_projects
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public/my-app
```

Running vagrant global-status I see.

```
id       name    provider    state   directory
5d79357  default virtual box running /Users/warrenday/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead
```

I have tried running homestead provision to restart the VM but I'm not sure if this is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using standard Laravel file structure, you're doing this the wrong way.

When installing Laravel, your public folder will look like this: `my-app/public` not `public/my-app`.

```
sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/my-app/public
```

And not sure if you missed something or its a MAC thing (windows guy here), but `/Users//Sites/laravel_projects` doesn't seem right (two //)

And unless you've already done this, you need to make sure that in your hosts file you add `192.168.10.10 homestead.app` (or your equivalent vagrant ip)

Comment: Thanks, your right I had it backwards! I had placed the laravel project inside a folder called public... so it would have been public/project-name/public